# Como unificar duas tabelas com chaves primárias repetidas?

Tags: microsoft-excel, table, tabela-html, merge

Tenho duas tabelas do qual precisamos unificar em uma só, de maneira completa: Considerar tudo que há na primeira, ver se bate com a segunda e o que não bater ou se repetir, incluir nas linhas do fim.

Veja que a chave 2 é repedida na segunda tabela, portanto, um procv não resolveria no caso de 2 ou mais incidências. A chave 5 não tem incidência na primeira tabela. Nesses casos, os mesmos foram inseridos no final da terceira tabela.

Segue exemplo:

```html
 Tabela 1         
          
A B C D E F     
1 Brasil Carro Honda Fit 100     
2 Chile Carro Honda CRV 200     
3 Russia Moto yamaha Crosser 150     
4 Russia Carro Volvo v40 300     
          
 Tabela 2         
          
U V X Y W Z     
1 Brasil P - - 100     
2 Chile - 4rodas - 100     
2 Uruguai G 4rodas - 100     
5 EUA G 8rodas Transporte 400     
          
 Tabela 3 unificada
       
A B C D E F V X Y W Z
1 Brasil Carro Honda Fit 100 Brasil P - - 100
2 Chile Carro Honda CRV 200 Chile - 4rodas - 100
3 Russia Moto yamaha Crosser 150     
4 Russia Carro Volvo v40 300     
5 EUA     EUA G 8rodas Transporte 400
2      Uruguai G 4rodas - 100
```

Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Parece um `cross join`, só que levando em consideração além de `tabela1.A = tabela2.U` outros fatores, como `tabela1.B = tabela2.V`

Comment: No link [How to simulate a full outer join in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/1023123/how-to-simulate-a-full-outer-join-in-excel), você vai encontrar 3 formas de resolver essa questão.